# saveing checkboxbutton in tableview

Tags: save, tableview, nsuserdefaults

i am working with Storybord and i got a tableview  with a checkboxbutton.

and i am  using  NSUserDefaults to save the state of my checkboxbutton i tried to save it with Core Data but i dont know how so its better to go to the easy way NSUserDefaults .

and the checkboxbutton is working great but the problem it does not save the state of the checkboxbutton !!!

when i close the app and open it again its not saved .

can any one please help me here i did all my best to solve this problem but no luck

here is my code

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;

@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL checked;


  @synthesize myButton,checked;


 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
checked = [defaults boolForKey:@"boxIsChecked"];
[defaults synchronize];
[self checkTheBox];

}

   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
    {
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = 
  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...
NSManagedObject *device = [self.Work objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[cell.textLabel setText= [Work valueForKey:@"name"]



myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] ;
[myButton setFrame:CGRectMake(260,2,40,40)];
myButton.tag = indexPath.row;
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonCheckMark:) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell addSubview:myButton];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


return cell;
}


- (IBAction)ButtonCheckMark:(id)sender {

myButton = (UIButton *)sender;
NSLog(@"playButton %li" , (long)myButton.tag);

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if (!checked) {
    [myButton setImage:
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBoxMarked.png"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    checked = YES;
    [defaults setBool:checked forKey:@"boxIsChecked"];
}

else if (checked) {
    [myButton setImage:
   [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    checked = NO;
    [defaults setBool:checked forKey:@"boxIsChecked"];
  }

[defaults synchronize];

   }
 - (void) checkTheBox {
if (!checked) {
    [myButton setImage:
  [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBox.png"]   forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   }

else if (checked) {

    [myButton setImage:
  [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBoxMarked.png"]   forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   }
   }
```

Comment: What is `checked` I don't see it defined anywhere (some ivar I assume). Also what is not working? Is it always returning NO or YES?

Comment: thanks for your reply , checked is a boolean and what is not working is when i close the app and open it again its not saved .

if i click on the button it is YES and if i click again its NO . but when i close the app and open it again its not saved the state will be always  NO .